# Are Google Play Services independently updtable for any smartphone? Error at Exposure Notifications Api for Covid-19

Tags: android, api, android-studio, incompatibility

I tried to install the sample released by Google with the new Exposure Notifications API at my quite new smartphone (not sure if I can mention the model) and I am getting "internal error".

Next step I launched the App at debug mode and I am getting the warning below. The question is, if there is a dependency between the Google Play Services (GPSv) and the software of the Smartphone, or they are independent, and in this case the former can be updated by Google at any time?

At the smartphone I don't see any way to upgrade the GPSv. Once this smartphones brand has a lot of success, there is the risk we, owners, cannot install any app with this API and that will be a huge limitation for relevant adoption (more of 70% they say).

What can I do at Android Studio to get the Sample working?

*W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 201550000 but found 201516037
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 201550000 but found 201516037
E/ENPermissionHelper: Unknown error or has hasInFlightResolution
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeoutFuture$TimeoutFutureException: Timed out (timeout delayed by 31 ms after scheduled time): androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$SafeFuture$1@3d634[status=PENDING, info=[tag=[GmsCoreTask]]]*
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are independently updatable, furthermore, you can join the beta tester program to access the latest version of play services released yesterday.
I have installed the latest beta on my device, and the sample app still throws "internal error"

Comment: thks, I will join the beta and try to debug the app to see if the error is different now

Comment: I have installed the Beta Google Play Services but debugging the app it still finds the old version 201516037. It is now 1.11 am so in few hours I will try to understand why the smartphone is not assuming the Beta version

Comment: Here's an issue and a discussion between me and a maintainer on the google sample app, turns out you need to be granted access by google and the only way to do that is for official health authorities of your country to contact google directly to get access : https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-android/issues/3

Comment: Hi Ayoub, yes I read that some hours ago, so no way to test the sample now. Anyway the message about GPS was real because it does not appear anymore. Now it fails because we are not "certified".